# how to get rid of "#REF!" error while "importxml" is loading data?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is it possible to get rid of #REF! error in a cell while the formula waits for the data which is being imported from a webpage using importxml function? I would like to not update a cell with new data until new data is imported so the #ref! error wont come up. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your formula in an =IFERROR

```
=IFERROR("Formula here"   ,  "")
```

Comment: well it does not work for me because it although the error disapears but also the content of a cell becomes blank and I wanted to leave the content of a cell until the new data has loaded. So for example if the value in a cell is 10 and i call a function to reload importxml I want this value 10 to stay in that cell until the new value arrives. With your formula value 10 disapears when the data is loading and new value in the cell apears when its loaded but I need this cell to be always filled with the value, either previous one or new one when it is loaded.

Comment: @ignac that's not how formulas work, you can't set a value to it dinamically until a new value you want is present, you'll need some script coding.

Comment: well I suspected that its not going to be easy and it will take more than just a formula. Any thoughts how would the script look like?